# Add HTML body to an email with Powershell

Tags: html, email, powershell, outlook, smtp

I'm using powershell to notify a high number of users about an expiration date of a document.

I have my script prepared

```
 $smtpServer = "xxxxx.contoso.com"
 $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
 $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
 $msg.From = New-Object Net.Mail.mailaddress "xxxx@contoso.es", "xxx yyy zzz"
 $msg.ReplyTo = "no-reply@contoso.es"
 $msg.To.Add("xxx@contoso.es")
 $msg.bcc.add($bcc)
 $msg.subject = "Expiration notification"
```

$msg.body = **I need to include HTML content, or MHT or bin as outlook message format.**

```
 $smtp.Send($msg)
```

But the email body was preformatted using outlook, so it contains images, preformated text etc. Which would be the best way to include that kind of content in the message body??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you add the Body as an html string and also add the line:

```
$msg.IsBodyHTML = true
```

Comment: it's not only a single html file but also a folder containing images... should it work anyway @ben?